# Indexing on JOIN and WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

If my query looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM member
LEFT JOIN group ON (member.group_id = group.id)
WHERE group.created > @date
ORDER BY member.last_updated
```

If I create two indexes for:

```
member.group_id, member.last_updated
group.id, group.created
```

Is that the best way to optimize the original query? Should I add a new field `member.group_created` and index that like so:

```
member.group_created, member.last_updated
```

Comment: I'd recommend checking with the EXPLAIN statement https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html for the two cases and see.

Comment: I bet adding that member.group_created would be of little use and would not speed up your query. You are breaking 3NF for convenience. The optimizer will correctly use the index on group.created. If you are going to do anything  to speed this up then test out adding a non-clustered index on member.last_updated

Comment: Just create two separate indexes-->1.member.group_id 2.group.created,i think 'id' in 'group' table will be primary key,No need to index that since primarys will be defaultly indexed in mysql

Comment: Good point that I could exclude the `group.id` from the second index, but this doesn't address the optimization from the ordering of the results by `member.last_updated`. Perhaps this isn't needed because we'd be scanning all the results that matched in `member` and thus an index wouldn't improve performance that much? However if this is the only query where we'd be interested in querying by `member.group_id` then adding the `member.last_updated` to the index is a minimal overhead, no?

Comment: Note that group is a reserved word- so a less than ideal choice for a table identifier

Comment: @timo Would you mind posting your comment as an answer. This comment lead me to a solution that I'm satisfied with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  member AS m
    LEFT JOIN  group AS g  ON (m.group_id = g.id)
    WHERE  g.created > @date
    ORDER BY  m.last_updated
```

- If you don't need all (`*`) the columns of both tables, don't ask for them; it may impact performance.
- Do you really need `LEFT`?  That is, do you want `NULL` for any rows missing from the 'right' table?
- If the Optimizer decides to start with `member`, it *might* benefit from `INDEX(last_updated)`.  Assuming that `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY of`group`, no extra index is needed there.
- If it decides to start with `group`, then `INDEX(created)` *may* be useful.  Then, `m` needs `INDEX(group_id)`.

So, add the 3 indexes I suggest, if they don't already exist.

If you have more issues, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0):

Dont use where clause on left join tables,instead do something like this.

SELECT *
FROM member

LEFT JOIN group ON (member.group_id = group.id and group.created > @date)

ORDER BY member.last_updated

Also add index (id,created) in group table

Comment: Please keep the `ON` to say how the tables are related.  Then have filtering clauses in the `WHERE`.

Comment: you are correct however you cannot put filter on left join since it slows down the performance,In inner join you you can do that

Comment: If the resultset is the same, then the Optimizer will "do the right thing".  If the resultset is different, who cares about the performance.